# windows service starts after another windows service function is finished

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have two windows services, Service_A and Service_B. And lets say, each service has more than 5 functions in them. I want, when one of the Service_A's function is finished, a function from Service_B gets started. How can I do that? I listed the steps I want

```
Service_A.function1() ... start
Service_A.function1() ... finish
Service_A.function1() ... triggers Service_B.functionX()
Service_B.functionX() ... start
Service_B.functionX() ... finish
```

Comment: Take a look at *[Inter process communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*

Comment: I didnt know Inter Process Communication but it seemd difficult to use it between services

Comment: Service_A.function1() must trigger Service_b.functionX() (via any IPC mechanism, just take a look to WCF - it's pretty easy - or simply an AutoResetEvent). As alternative you may setup an observer to do this (but Service_A must then expose proper _events_).

Comment: I liked IPC but I didnt understand how I can get the benefit of IPC. Can you guys give me a simple example with IPC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`EventWaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this.  Below is a very simple example using two console applications.  Here is the code for the application that does the triggering:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static EventWaitHandle _event;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _event = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "foobar");

            Func1();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Func1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - Func1() Started...", DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - Func1() Finished..", DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            _event.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the application that is triggered:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static EventWaitHandle _event;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _event = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "foobar");
            _event.WaitOne();
            Func1();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Func1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - Func1() Started...", DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - Func1() Finished..", DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

To run this, start ConsoleApplication2 first, and then start ConsoleApplication1.

Some things to note...

This works because both applications use the same named event, "foobar".  This name ought to be unique system-wide, so you might want to consider generating a GUID and using that as the name, e.g., "{EEABFFAD-A5CF-4C70-A6C5-CAD7B7AAD004}".  This will avoid any reasonable possibility of conflicts.

Note that in order for this example to work as you've described, ConsoleApplication2 has to run first.  When you apply this to your services, you'll probably want to construct things so that it doesn't matter which service gets started first.  That's just part of bullet-proofing things, but something to be mindful of.

Also note that ConsoleApplication2 calls [`WaitOne()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx).  This function blocks until the event is triggered.  If the event is never triggered, it blocks forever.  You might want to consider replacing this with a timeout loop so that you can also check if the service needs to shutdown.  For example,

```
// Create a 'shutdown' ManualResetEvent in the OnStart() method. 
// Set it in the OnStop() method to trigger this thread to stop
// executing.
while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
{
    // Wait for 1 second before timing out.  If return is true,
    // the event was triggered.
    if (_event.WaitOne(1000))
    {
        Func1();
    }
}
```

HTH